# Active Directory 2008 R2, c#

Tags: powershell, active-directory, c#

I am using C# and trying to check if a group exists or not in active directory
I am doing this

```
string cmd = "New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry \"LDAP://cn=" + groupname + " " + LdapDef + ",dc=twu,dc=ca\" | Select-Object name";
string result = execute(cmd);
return true;
```

this used to work in the past but from a while now I get following error whenever above code is executed.

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> The following exception occurred while    retrieving member "name": "There is no such object on the server.

" ---> The following exception occurred while retrieving member "name": "There is no such object on the server.

" ---> There is no such object on the server.
```

I am not sure what is wrong here? what else could i use to get the groupname other than using "name"

Can someone help me this please?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to search our directory:

```
 DirectoryEntry objDE;
 objDE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=computers,dc=lab,dc=test");
 static String[] strProperties = { "name" };

 DirectorySearcher dd = new DirectorySearcher(objDE, "(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=user)(cn=name))", strProperties, SearchScope.Subtree);
```

this is C#, I've never mixed C# and powershell but this should get point you in the right direction. don't forget

```
Using System.DirectoryServices
```

also.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx